# CollectionView prepareForSegue Not Sending Image Data to DetailView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I have a `CollectionView` setup that displays remote image data from server. I am able to view the images in the `CollectionView`, but nothing shows when I tap the item for the `DetailView`. It was working properly while I used local images, but after adding the **"SDWebImage framework"**, I am unable to view the images when I tap them for `DetailView`. I believe the issue lies with the `prepareForSegue` method, but nothing I have tried will solve the issue. I have searched many questions on "StackOverflow", but was unable to find an answer for this specific issue.

Here is my code for `CollectionViewController`:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.thumbnailView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];

    return cell;

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"displayDetail"]) {
        PhotoViewController *destViewController = (PhotoViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:sender];
        NSString *imagePath = [photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imagePath];
        NSLog(@"Image named: %@ at row %ld", imagePath, (long)indexPath.row);
        destViewController.largeImage = image;
    }
}
```

The segue triggers fine, but just displays a white screen in `PhotoViewController.m` after being tapped.

Comment: If you log image in prepareForSegue, does it give you the right thing? How are you displaying the image in the PhotoViewController -- you're passing an image, do you set that on an image view?

Comment: @rdelmar The NSLog I have in prepareForSegue shows `Image named: http://192.168.22.31:9999/IMG_0001.JPG at row 1`, which is the correct URL for the image.

Comment: @rdelmar `largeImage` is declared as a `UIImage` property in `PhotoViewController.h`, and displayed in `viewDidLoad` as `imageView.image = self.largeImage;`

Comment: I asked about logging image, not imagePath. If you log image, doe sit give you a UIImage object?

Comment: @rdelmar Sorry, I misunderstood. If I log `NSLog(@"%@", image);` it shows `(null)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reworking quite a bit of how I was displaying the data, and managed to get it to work.

Here's the code I used:

**CollectionViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PhotoViewController.h"
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"

@class PhotoViewController;

@interface CollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) PhotoViewController *photoViewController;

@end
```

**CollectionViewController.m**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"displayDetail"]) {
    PhotoViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] lastObject];
    NSString *largeImageURL = [photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    destViewController.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:largeImageURL];
    }
}
```

**PhotoViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CollectionViewController.h"

@interface PhotoViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *imageURL;

@end
```

**PhotoViewController.m**

```
#import "PhotoViewController.h"
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"

@interface PhotoViewController ()

@end

@implementation PhotoViewController

@synthesize imageURL = _imageURL;
@synthesize imageView = _imageView;

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setImageURL:(NSURL *)imageURL
{
    if (_imageURL != imageURL)
    {
        _imageURL = imageURL;
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    if (self.imageURL)
        // NSLog(@"%@", self.imageURL);
    {
        // NSLog(@"%@", self.imageView);
        [self.imageView setImageWithURL:self.imageURL placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
         {
         }
             completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
         {
             // NSLog(@"%@", image);
         }];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureView];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in your code, you build up your thumbnailView using the `setImageWithURL` method of the `SDWebImage` class.

Then when you build up your large view, you pass the url of the image to `[UIImage imageNamed:imagePath]`.

From the documentation of SDWebImage, I see it's an extension to UIImageView. So you can simply call `[destViewController.imageView setImageWithURL:...]` in your segue preparation.

Your `prepareForSegue`should then look something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"displayDetail"]) {
        PhotoViewController *destViewController = (PhotoViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:sender];
        NSString *imagePath = [photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"Image named: %@ at row %ld", imagePath, (long)indexPath.row);

        [destViewController.imageView
                     setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagePath]
                    placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"] 
                             options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

In the `viewDidLoad` of your PhotoViewController you will not have to do anything about this.
Just make sure you import `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>` in the file where you implemented `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Using this method, do I just add `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>` and pass `[self imageView];` in `PhotoViewController.m`, or would I need to create another `CollectionView` to display the image? Sorry, I'm new to iOS and this is the first time I've used a `CollectionView`.

Comment: @JohnBlanchard Please take a look at my recent edit. Let me know if it solved your problem.